# Determine values of a and b such that f(x) is continuous at x = 1.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

a) If we want the function to be continuous at x = 1, does that mean that both of the one-sided limits equal to 2? In that case, would I plug in that y-value and a random x-value that satisfies the restrictions to find the possible values of a and b?

b) x cannot be -2

x has to be bigger than or equal to -b.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x)=\frac{3}{1+2}-a
= \lim\limits_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x)=\sqrt{b+1}=2=f(1)$

$a=-1, b=3$